# Checking Each Value in For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I've searched for an answer for this but haven't found one that cover this well with a good example.

I have a for loop:

```
for (var i=0;i<userProfileProperties.length;i++) {
  if (userProfileProperties[i].indexOf("ValueImSearchingFor") {
   console.log("GOTIT");
  }
  }
```

I'm trying to test each value in the loop to see if it contains a certain set of letters. If it doesn't, that value can be dropped. I can't get this to work. I've searched and have found examples but none seem do what I'm trying to do. or at least I've found no "working" example. I'm new to javascript.

So if my values in the loop returned normally would be: Jack User1, Jill User1, and Jerry User2; the values I want returned are all "User1"

I can't get this to work for:

```
while(userEnumerator.moveNext()){ 
var oUser = userEnumerator.get_current();    
if(oUser.val.indexOf('ValueImsearchingFor') > -1) 
{ ... do this} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.filter()` method available for arrays as below:

**ES5**

```
var res = userProfileProperties.filter(function (val) {
  return val.indexOf("ValueImSearchingFor") > -1
});
```

**ES6**

```
let res = userProfileProperties.filter((val) => {
  return val.indexOf("ValueImSearchingFor") > -1
});
```

```js
let userProfileProperties = [
  'ValueImSearchingFor 1',
  'ValueImSearchingFor 2',
  'test',
  'ValueImSearchingFor 3',
  'test 1'
  ];

let res = userProfileProperties.filter((val) => {
      return val.indexOf("ValueImSearchingFor") > -1
    });

console.log(res);
```

Comment: would that be "userProfileProperties[i].filter"?

Comment: No. The `.filter` method is called on an array. `userProfileProperties[i]`will give you the value at index `i`. See the working example I have updated in the post

Comment: Thanks, Aditya, I can't get this to work for  "while(userEnumerator.moveNext()){ var oUser = userEnumerator.get_current(); if(oUser.val.indexOf('ValueImsearchingFor') > -1) { ... do this} }